# AutoHotKey Play/Pause Youtube

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to remap my Surface Pen button click to pause/unpause youtube in Chrome. I can get it to work if Chrome is not focused, or if Chrome is focused and youtube is the active tab, but it doesn't work if Chrome is focused but youtube is not the active tab.

This is what I have:

```
    #NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
    #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
    SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
    SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

    SetTitleMatchMode 2

    #IfWinNotActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
    #F20::
        ControlGet, controlID, Hwnd,,Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1, Google Chrome
        ControlFocus,,ahk_id %controlID%
        tabCount := 0
        Loop {
            IfWinExist, YouTube
                break
            ControlSend, , ^{PgUp} , Google Chrome
            sleep 150
            tabCount := tabCount + 1
            if tabCount = 10
                break
        }
        if tabCount < 10
            ControlSend, , k , Google Chrome
        Loop, %tabCount% {
            ControlSend, , ^{PgDn} , Google Chrome
            sleep 150
        }
        return
    #IfWinNotActive

    #IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
    #F20::
        tabCount := 0
        Loop {
            IfWinExist, YouTube
                break
            ControlSend, , ^{PgUp} , Google Chrome
            sleep 150
            tabCount := tabCount + 1
            if tabCount = 10
                break
        }
        if tabCount < 10
            ControlSend, , k , Google Chrome
        Loop, %tabCount% {
            ControlSend, , ^{PgDn} , Google Chrome
            sleep 150
        }
        return
    #IfWinActive
```

Comment: You may be able to simplify this by simply mapping the button to Key Code 179, which is the Play/Pause code used by most media-control-enabled keyboards. See [this enumeration of codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is enough:

```
    #NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
    #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
    SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
    SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

    #F20::Media_Play_Pause
```